# How to output an array index in fetched data in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The following code makes an API request and displays all indices received, which is a JSON response.

Instead of rendering a list, I need to output a single data array index obtained from the server response:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }
  //request to api
  loadData() {
    fetch('https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          data: data
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(this.props.url, err.toString()))
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //conclusion data
      {
        this.state.data.map((item) => {
          return <div class = "mypanel" > currency: {
            item.ccy
          }
          exchange: {
            item.buy
          } < /div>
        })
      }
    )
    React.render(document.getElementById('mypanel'));
  }
}

export default Test;
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear , what do you mean by ' output a single data array index obtained from api '. Do you mean the length of the data array perhaps ?

Comment: I meant to output a certain array index instead of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display an item corresponding to a particular index from the list of items received from server. You can do it as:

```
<div class = "mypanel" > 
currency: { this.state.data[index].ccy} exchange: {
            this.state.data[index].buy
          } < /div>
```

where 'index' is the index value that you want to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display only certain items depending upon some conditions then you can use filter function from array and filter your items like below.

```
this.state.data.filter(item=>{
   return item.buy=== "buy"?true:false;
}).map((item) => {
          return <div class = "mypanel" > currency: {
            item.ccy
          }
          exchange: {
            item.buy
          } < /div>
})
```

If you want to show only certain no of items then you can use for loop or forEach and take only required no of items. You can write a separate function and call same like below.

```
function ShowSome(noOfItemsToTake){
      const items = [];
      const data = this.state.data; 
      const noOfItems=  noOfItemsToTake< data.length?noOfItemsToTake:data.length; 

          for (let i=0; i<noOfItems;i++)
          {
            items.push(  
              <div class = "mypanel" > currency: {
                data[i].ccy
              }
              exchange: {
                data[i].buy
              } < /div>) 
          }
     return items;  
}




render() {
    //Showing first 5   
    return this.ShowSome(5);
 }
```